# Neo4j/Lucene - How to create a unique index?

Tags: lucene, indexing, neo4j

I'm using Neo4j, and I wonder if it is possible to create a lucene index with a unique field. (that is, every key/value pair can be associated with only one node)

For example, i want to achieve the following behavior:

```
someIndex.add(node1, "firstName", "Roy");
someIndex.add(node2, "firstName", "John");

// Here I expect to recieve an exception because the key/value pair (firstName, Roy) is already associated with node1
someIndex.add(node3, "firstName", "Roy");
```

Is it possible to achieve something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: Lucene has no notion of 'nodes' (as a graph concept). It's not really clear to me what you try to accomplish.

Comment: My question is more related to neo4j indexes. I just want to know if it possible to create a unique index.

Comment: If your question is more related to neo4j indexes then you should edit it to remove "lucene" from in front of "index".

Answer (score 0):

On Java API level you can use [UniqueFactory](http://api.neo4j.org/1.9/org/neo4j/graphdb/index/UniqueFactory.html). For usage example, check out http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/transactions-unique-nodes.html.

Answer (score 0):

In my code I'm using the BatchInserterIndex and add a map of key and values I need to be indexed..
The code is something like this:

```
BatchInserterIndex myIndex = indexProvider.nodeIndex("myIndex", MapUtil.stringMap("type", "exact"));
Map<String, Object> key_Value_IndexMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
key_Value_IndexMap.put("ID", value);
myIndex.add(createdNodeId, key_Value_IndexMap);
```